# Bootstrap Switch Button can not get false state

Tags: spring-boot, bootstrap-5

In my code I am trying to get Bootstrap Switch Button state. I have DTO to hold value and pass it to controller class. Also I have requestparam statement to get current state. But I could not get the false value. There is no problem with true value. Default is true. when I changed to (means setting button off state) false I am getting error. Here is my code shortly,

```
<div class="form-check form-switch">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="switchminoraxis" name="switchminoraxis" checked>
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="switchminoraxis">Major Axis</label>
                        </div>

@PostMapping("/selectbeam")
    public String CalculateBeam(@Valid @ModelAttribute("calbeamr") CalBeamResultDto calBeamResultDto,
                              @RequestParam("switchminoraxis") boolean sminoraxis,
                              RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) throws IOException, ParseException {

        calBeamResultDto.setSwitchminoraxis(sminoraxis);
        calBeamResultDto.setSectiontype(sectiontype);
        calBeamResultDto.setBeamsection(beamsection);
        calBeamResultDto.setCasetype(casetype);



Required parameter 'switchminoraxis' is not present.
org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required request parameter 'switchminoraxis' for method parameter type boolean is not present
```

Answer (score 0):

I have handled the situation by adding required property of requestparam to false. This gives default false value and conditionaly I have check parameters.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).